# How to get the next value from a JSONObject

Tags: java, php, arrays, json

I have this information from a .php file:

```
"{"limitacao_motora":[{"descricaoLimitacao":"Wheelchair"}]}
 {"limitacao_motora":[{"descricaoLimitacao":"Crutches"}]}
 {"limitacao_motora":[{"descricaoLimitacao":"Walk short distances"}]}
 {"limitacao_motora":[{"descricaoLimitacao":"Only short stairs"}]}
 {"limitacao_motora":[{"descricaoLimitacao":"Only short stairs"}]}"
```

I need to separate each option into a textView in android studio. But I only can get the first name "Wheelchair".

My code is to get the information is:

```
JSONObject reader2 = new JSONObject(resp);
final JSONObject limitacao_motora =
        (JSONObject) reader2.getJSONArray("limitacao_motora").get(0);
```

And to put the information into the textView is:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.limi))
        .setText(limitacao_motora.getString("descricaoLimitacao"));"
```

My output is the textView "limi" with the word "wheelchair".
Now I need to put "Crutches" into other textView but I don't know how.

I'm a newbie in this, I searched but I don't understand my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please create your data json accepted.. i think the data is wrong. i try to validate with jslint, and the result is wrong. -- > https://imgur.com/jonDShI

Answer (score 0):

As @muhammadaa said, your json it's a little bit weird.
Do you have the power to adjust your json response?
If the answer is yes, take a look at this alternative model:

```
{
   "limitacao_motora": true,
   "descricaoLimitacao": ["Wheelchair", "Crutches", "Walk short 
    distances", "Only Short stairs"]
}
```

With this JSON response you can know if the condition **limitacao_motora** is applicable for your current object and you can retrieve your **descricaoLimitacao** array values like that:

```
//Retrieve your array
JSONArray descricoesLimitacoes = yourJsonResponse.getJSONArray("descricaoLimitacao");
```

With your JSONArray array object ready you can call **get** method passing an array index value to retrieve its value.

So, i hope that this answer can give you some clarifications and ideas to improve your code implementation :)

If you have any trouble, please, let me know so i can help you to solve it!